# T-test with equal variance but large, unequal sample sizes

Tags: t-test

For an independent samples t-test, I have two groups with equal variance (Levene's not significant) but the sample sizes are quite different. Example one: Group one N = 366 ; Group Two N = 174. Example 2: Group one N = 74 ; Group two N = 261.

My main question: Does the size difference matter if the variances are equal? [I am using SPSS for my t-test analysis.]

(Secondary question: I saw something about using pooled SD for unequal sample sizes--does SPSS do that?)

Thanks,
Laura